# Regression Loss Function Working Perfectly on My Classification Model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, multilabel-classification, multiclass-classification

I have built a model that detects what type of shot a table tennis player is performing using TensorFlow. After I built my Neural Network, the model I am dealing with seems to be a multi-label classification model. The binary cross-entropy and categorical cross-entropy gave bad loss and accuracy while using MSE and MAE gave 98% accuracy and 0.004 loss in both cases.

Why is this happening, although I have Supervised Learning data with 3 output labels as shown in the figure below:
[The dataset I have collected showing 3 output labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y0Sk6.png)

Answer (score -1):

If your learner has .98 for R squared (of I understand you well), it is likely that you're overfitting and will hence have poor testing predictions. Prediction errors that low are typically symptomatic of overfitting... but honestly, this is likely a better query for cross-validated.

Comment: If "*honestly, this is likely a better query for cross-validated*", then please refrain from answering; see the relevant [community guidelines](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/276572/should-one-advise-on-off-topic-questions)

Comment: I tested the model 10s of times but no overfitting, even the validation loss is about 0.006